# MySQL Function and CodeIgniter Active Record

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, php

CodeIgniter Active Record is easy, well documented and powerful. But when I try to insert MySQL built in functions `CONCAT`, `NOW`, `GROUP_CONCAT`, `DATEDIFF`, `TRIM` etc or my custom functions it is giving errors. The following code works fine...

```
$result = $this->db->select('p.first_name, p.last_name, p.mobile_number, p.email_address')->from('profile p')->get()->result();
```

But When I want to contact `first_name` and `last_name` and use MySQL `CONCAT` function like this...

```
$result = $this->db->select('CONCAT(p.first_name, " ", p.last_name) fullname, p.mobile_number, p.email_address')->from('profile p')->get()->result();
```

It is showing database errors

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '", `p`.`last_name)` fullname, `p`.`mobile_number`, `p`.`email_address` FROM (`pr' at line 1

SELECT CONCAT(p.first_name, `"` ", `p`.`last_name)` fullname, `p`.`mobile_number`, `p`.`email_address` FROM (`profile` p)

Filename: D:\xampp\htdocs\example\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

Is there a any way to insert MySQL Functions inside CodeIgniter Active Record? Hope I am clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [CONCAT() function in a SELECT field list](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4519838) and example: [concat in php codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4623958).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- FIXED THE ISSUE

adding the field names in active record array can fix this problem. inside array you can use any mysql functions. the fix of above.

MySQL Table :

```
fullname             mobile_number  email_address                 
-------------------  -------------  ------------------------------
sitaramaiah javvadi  9989403339     gnt.sitaramaiah@mstonline.in  
raja kumar guthula   9949526012     gnt.rajkumar@mstonline.in     
chandra sekhar k.l   9912144556     gnt.sekhar@mstonline.in       
khadar  basha        98884884584    khadar333332@gmail.com        
super administrator  9841866445     admin@gmail.com
```

CodeIgniter Active Record :

```
$result = $this->db->select(array('CONCAT(p.first_name, " ", p.last_name) `fullname`', 'p.mobile_number', 'p.email_address'))->from('profile `p`')->get()->result();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [fullname] => sitaramaiah javvadi
            [mobile_number] => 9989403339
            [email_address] => gnt.sitaramaiah@mstonline.in
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [fullname] => raja kumar guthula
            [mobile_number] => 9949526012
            [email_address] => gnt.rajkumar@mstonline.in
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [fullname] => chandra sekhar k.l
            [mobile_number] => 9912144556
            [email_address] => gnt.sekhar@mstonline.in
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [fullname] => khadar  basha
            [mobile_number] => 98884884584
            [email_address] => khadar333332@gmail.com
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [fullname] => super administrator
            [mobile_number] => 9841866445
            [email_address] => admin@gmail.com
        )

)
```

Answer (score 4):

Since I don't know your exact error:

From user_guide:

> $this->db->select() accepts an optional second parameter. If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names with backticks. This is useful if you need a compound select statement.

```
$result = $this->db->select('CONCAT(p.first_name, " ", p.last_name) fullname, p.mobile_number, p.email_address', FALSE)->from('profile p')->get()->result();
```

Comment: @Madan I'm inclined to agree with Bernhard -- if you look at your error closely, you will notice the extra `\`` before a `"` and after the completion of the CONCAT method. That seems to be the problem.

Comment: @Madan Your options are to either use FALSE or not use the `select` method.

Answer (score 1):

Place you "select " in array 
$this->db->select(array('CONCAT(p.first_name, " ", p.last_name) fullname, p.mobile_number, p.email_address'))

by.

Answer (score 1):

For the case of update using active records you can use

```
$this->db->set("date_read", "NOW()", FALSE);
```

Will output something like this

```
`SET `date_read` = NOW(),
```

Comment: @Goodluck, I know the `FALSE` parameter. I was searching without `FALSE` and I already updated the answer too.

Comment: `FALSE` is needed here, else something that you don't want to be escaped will be escaped. So avoid injecting "dynamic" (user-input = untrusted) data with this as that (`$someFooPostData`) will lead to SQJ injection attacks.

**Do always** use this with great care.

Here, my Active-Record-Pattern-based approach for updating columns with SQL functions did work with this.